# How to show an unobtrusive message when invalid input is entered in an edit control

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created an edit control for user name which allows to enter only alpha characters. When the users tries to enter any special characters or numbers, a message box will pop up with a message that these are not allowed.

I used `AfxMessageBox()` to show the message but it is not looking good, the user has to manually press OK when the message is shown. Is there any way to show and hide a message automatically?

It should behave in the same way as the message that appears when an edit control is created with the `ES_NUMBER` style and the user enters a non-numeric character:
[image: edit control balloon tooltip]

Comment: Don't show a message box that must be clicked away. Just use color and/or flashing, perhaps a short-lived status message. If anything (the lack of response is telling in itself).

Comment: You can use EditBox's OnChanged() handler, if the content contains unwanted character, you can show it on a static text below the editbox for short duration only.

Comment: Showing a modal dialog is inevitably going to be intrusive, even if you close the dialog after a given timeout. What you should be doing instead is to give the user non-intrusive feedback (e.g. by showing an icon next to the edit control, with a tooltip explaining, what's wrong), as well as disable the dialog's accept button.

Comment: Your question title isn't really helpful. Please read this: [ask].

Comment: I have edited your question to make it a little bit easier to understand. I hope it still expresses your intend.

Comment: @seccpur: In this case, I think you want the `EN_UPDATE` notification. `EN_UPDATE` is sent immediately before redrawing, EN_CHANGE immediately after redrawing. We don't want an illegal character to be displayed, so we want to react to `EN_UPDATE` by removing the character and popping up the warning for a prohibited character (which, as a result, is never shown to the user).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Great suggestion, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> It should behave in the same way as the message that appears when an edit 
>   control is created with the `ES_NUMBER` style and the user enters a non-numeric
>   character.

In this case, the default window procedure shows a [balloon tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/ctrl-balloons).

This could be implemented like this:

1. Handle the [`EN_UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/en-update) notification to detect whether the user has entered invalid characters in the edit control, *before* the text is shown. This handles the cases of individual key presses as well as copy/paste operations.
2. When the input is valid, store the window text in a member variable.
3. When the input is invalid, restore the last known "good" text from the member variable. As a result, the invalid characters are never shown to the user. Call the [`ShowBalloonTip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=vs-2017#showballoontip) member function of the `CEdit` class (which sends it a `EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP` message). There is no need to explicitly create a tooltip control as this is managed by the edit control.

In step 3) you propably also have to save/restore the current selection (I'm not sure whether `EN_UPDATE` is send before or after selection change).

Example for calling `ShowBalloonTip()`:

```
m_edit.ShowBalloonTip( L"Some Title", L"Some Text", TTI_ERROR );
```